# how to access express module for other js file , express module is already included in app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let Me explain what I am working on .
I have included the express module in `app.js` .
Here I want to access this module in `index.js` , `admin.js` , `gallery.js`.
but I dont want to write the same code again in all over js file .

let me show you my scenario.

```html
app.js has

var express = require('express');
```

index.js has

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

```js
gallery.js has

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('gallery', { title: 'Gallery' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here `var express = require('express');` is already present in `app.js` .
I want to reuse it from `app.js` instead of including in every file .

What I have tried so far

I made global in app.js , so that I can access it all over

```
global.express = require('express');
```

this code is working for me .

Is this the correct approach **or** any other way to do **or** including express module in all the js file is fine ?

Answer (score 1):

You can export your files (not app.js assuming this is your entry point) as a function and pass your express module into those files

**gallery.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) { 
 /* GET users listing. */
 app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('gallery', { title: 'Gallery' });
 }); 
}
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var galleryRoute = require('./gallery');

// Routes
galleryRoute(app);
```

Comment: yes its working in my case . but here we can not use express router instead of router.get  i have to use app.get

Answer (score 1):

I have read some where to avoid using Global Variables because there are some cons of it here are few of them:

- The first reason is that when you create a global variable, it exists
  throughout the lifetime of the application. When a variable persists
  through the lifetime of the app it means that it is there, in memory,
  occupying resources while the app is running.

  Second, traditionally using global variables can cause concurrency
  issues. If multiple threads can access the same variable and there
  are no access modifiers or failsafes in place, it can lead to some
  serious issues of two threads attempting to access and use the same
  variable. However, while this is the case in other languages, it is
  not necessarily the case for Node.js as it is strictly a
  single-threaded environment. While it is possible to cluster Node
  processes, there is no native way to communicate between them.

  The last reason I am going to talk about is that using globals can
  cause implicit coupling between files or variables. Coupling is not a
  good thing when it comes to writing great code. When writing code, we
  want to make sure that it is as modular and reusable as possible,
  while also making sure it is easy to use and understand. Coupling
  pieces of your code together can lead to some major headaches down
  the road when you are trying to debug why something isn't working.

As for your question you can export the express from app.js or index and use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is discouraged to use additional global variables as application already has 'export' and 'require' global variables. (exports/require are not keywords, but global variables.)

If you need to export the 'app' for other files, you can do something like below.

### in index.js:

var express_app = module.exports = express();

now index.js can be required to bring app into any file.

### in any.js file:

var express_app = require('./index');

Comment: it seems fine for me  but code is not working  in my case